# Namespaces and inheritance: super constructor with JavaScript chain of responsibility

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, namespaces, chain-of-responsibility

I'm working with namespaces, classes, inheritance and pattern chain of responsibility with JavaScript, but it doesn't work - I've tried following [this tutorial](https://github.com/phpmx/js-prototype-inherit-ways), but when I try to implement a namespace and a super constructor, it doesn't works, so I assume I'm missing something.

I have the classes in different files, and I use the same namespace. I have a class, `Constraint.js`:

```js
var Namespace = Namespace || {};

//parent class
Namespace.Constraint = (function() {

    //How can I do a constructor with the namespace?
    /**
        function Namespace.Constraint(value, succesor, type) {
            this.value = value;
            this.succesor = succesor;
            this.type = type;
            this.noTopic = "UNDEFINED";
        }
    */

    Namespace.Constraint.prototype.handle = function() {
        if (this.has()) {
            return this.succesor.handle();
        }
    }
    Namespace.Constraint.prototype.has = function() {
        return this.type != this.noTopic;
    }
    return Constraint;
})();
```

And the next is the class that has inheritance, and it is in the other file, `StringConstraint.js`:

```js
 var Namespace = Namespace ||{};

 Namespace.StringConstraint = (function(_super){

     /**Constructor child*/
     /*
     Namespace.StringConstraint = function(value, succesor) {
         _super.call(value, succesor, "string");
         How to call the constructor of the parent?
     }
     */

     Namespace.StringConstraint.prototype.handle = function() {

         if (this.has()) {
            return "type=text";
         }
         else{

            /* Is this the correct way to call a method of the parent? */
            _super.prototype.handle.call(this);
         }
     }

     Namespace.StringConstraint.prototype.has=function(){
        /* this.type is a value of parent class. Is this the correct way
           to call it? Maybe I should use _super.type?

        */
        return this.type === "string";
     }
     return Namespace.StringConstraint;

 })(Namespace.Constraint); //Reference to parent, but is it fine with the namespace?
```

And the class `BuilderConstraint.js`:

```js
 var Namespace = Namespace ||{};

 Namespace.BuilderConstraint = (function() {
     this.constraints = new Array();

        Namespace.BuilderConstraint.prototype.add = function( constraint ) {
            this.constraints.push(constraint);
        }
        Namespace.BuilderConstraint.prototype.applyConstraint  = function(callback) {
        for (constraint in this.constraints) {

            //How to ensure that class is Constraint?
            //Because I could get object [index], has not a method handle.
            callback(constraint.handle());
        }
    }
 })();
```

And finally the file `app.js`, that is my Main:

```js
 $(function() {
     var value = "string";
     var builderConstraint = new Namespace.BuilderConstaint();
     var stringConstraint = new Namespace.StringConstraint(value,null);
     builderConstraint.add(stringConstraint);

     builderConstraint.applyConstraint(function(out) {
         console.log(out);
     })
 });
```

I hope not to be very awkward, but I'm very confused.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I properly use the namespace in different JavaScript files?
2. How can I add a class without overwriting the namespace?
3. How can I write the constructor of class with a namespace?
4. How can I use the constructor of a class parent in the
   constructor of a class child?
5. What is the right way to use inheritance classes with a namespace?
6. How do I properly use the parents attributes in child classes?

This is a class Constraint(Parent Class):

```js
/**
 *  Clase padre
 */

var XMLFormBuilder  = XMLFormBuilder  || {};

XMLFormBuilder.Constraint= (function()
{
    function Constraint( value, succesor, type ) {
    this.value = value || "UNDEFINED";
    this.succesor = succesor || null;
    this.type = type || "UNDEFINED";
    this.noTopic = "UNDEFINED";
};

Constraint.prototype.handle = function()
{
    if (typeof null != this.succesor ) {
    {
       return this.succesor.handle();
    }
};

Constraint.prototype.has = function()
{
    return this.type != this.noTopic;
};

return Constraint;

})(); // <-- **Here, there is a trouble.**
```

The class `StringConstraint` (Child class):

```js
/**Child class*/
var XMLFormBuilder = XMLFormBuilder || {};

XMLFormBuilder.StringConstraint=(function(_super)
{
    function StringConstraint(value, succesor)
    {
        this.value = value || "UNDEFINED";
        this.succesor = succesor || null;
        _super.call( this.value, this.succesor, "cadena" );

       /**
        * How to I do to use the constructor of class parent in the constructor of class child?
        * Aquí hay un error, porque no se como llamar correctamente al contructor
        * de la clase padre o como lo sugiere el error que _super no esta definido.
        * Cannot call method 'call' of undefined;
       */

    };
    /* Aquí se genera un error si activo la sobreescritura del prototipo:
        Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) /entidad/js/Constraint.js:28
        Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function StringConstraint.js:16
        Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

        There is a trouble, because I can't overwrite the prototype
    */
    //StringConstraint.prototype = new _super;

    StringConstraint.prototype.handle=function()
    {
        if(this.has())
            return "type='text'";
        else
           return _super.handle();
    };

    StringConstraint.prototype.has = function()
    {
        return this.type === "cadena";
    }

    return StringConstraint;

    })(XMLFormBuilder.Constraint);
```

This is a Class `BuilderConstraint`:

```js
var XMLFormBuilder = XMLFormBuilder || {};

XMLFormBuilder.BuilderConstraint = (function()
{
    function BuilderConstraint() {
        this.constraints = new Array();
    }
    BuilderConstraint.prototype.add = function(constraint){
        this.constraints.push(constraint);
    }

    BuilderConstraint.prototype.applyContraints = function()
    {
        var out = "";
        /*
            this.constraints.forEach(function(object){
                out += object.handle();
            });
        */

        for (var index in this.constraints) {
            var constraint = this.constraints[index];
            /* Aquí se me presenta un error, ya que no me
            *  reconoce el método handle de los objetos tipo Constraint
            *  que agrege al array
            */
            out+= constraint.handle();
        }
        return out;
    }
    return BuilderConstraint;
})();
```

This is the `app.js`:

```js
$(function()
{
    var value = "cadena";
    var stringConstraint = new XMLFormBuilder.StringConstraint(value);
    var builderConstraint = new XMLFormBuilder.BuilderConstraint();
    builderConstraint.add(stringConstraint);
    console.log(builderConstraint.applyContraints());
});

/**
* This is the summary the problems:
*   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) Constraint.js:28
*   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
*/
```

You can see the code here: https://gist.github.com/cristianchaparroa/f4ace75aeb8cff04181a

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
Namespace.Constraint = (function(){

   // Create a function in the current execution context
   function Constraint( value, succesor, type ){
      this.value = value;
      this.succesor = succesor;
      this.type = type;
      this.noTopic = "UNDEFINED";

  }

  // Assign to the above function's prototype
  Constraint.prototype.handle =function(){
     if( this.has() ){
         return this.succesor.handle();
      }
  }

  Constraint.prototype.has = function(){
     return this.type != this.noTopic;
  }

  // Return the function so it is assigned to Namespace.Constraint
  return Constraint;

})();
```

Inside the immediately invoked function expression (IIFE), you can call the function *Constraint* anything you like since the name is local to the function. The return value is a reference to that function object and is assigned to *Namespace.Constraint*.

Comment: It resolve my questions, but how to I do to  resolve the new mistake  `Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'handle'`  in `BuilderConstraint.js` in the foreach, why my constraint not have my method `handle`?

Comment: The IIFE on the RHS of the assignment to *Namespace.BuilderConstraint* doesn't return anything, so *Namespace.BuilderConstraint* is undefined. If you've fixed that, post your new code.